# Model changes to widgets (price/description) over time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, schema, vestal-versions

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217302/database-schema-design-question-regarding-updates-to-items-for-sale-over-time) and the answer makes alot of sense to me. Now I ponder how those answers hold up in an environment like Rails where there are plugins/gems available like, say, vestal_versions?

If I'm selling widgets and the price and/or description of the item will change over time and Rails is my framework. How would *you* approach/model it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but wouldn't just have a table that carries your products, their descriptions, and the price?